# Find the Laplace transform of $g(t) = 1+cos^2(2t)$ by direct integration

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I'm having trouble finding out how to directly integrate the function $f(t)$ because of the $\cos^2(2t)$ term.  I understand that $\cos^2(2t) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos(4t)$ but I don't understand how this simplifies the problem so that

$\int_0^\infty {e^{-st}} + \int_0^\infty {e^{-st}(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos(4t))}$

Is an easier integral to solve.

Comment: $\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)$ can integrated by parts or by looking at it as the real part of $\int e^{(a+ib)x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that $\cos(4 t) = \Re e^{4 i t}$ so
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-st} \cos (4 t) dt &= \Re \int_0^\infty e^{(-s+4i)t} dt = \Re\frac{e^{(-s+4i)t}}{-s+4i}\Bigg|_{t=0}^{t=\infty} = -\Re \frac{1}{-s+4i}\\
&= \Re \frac{s + 4i}{s^2 +16} = \frac{s}{s^2 +16}
\end{align}